# Problems with supporting tablets and handsets simultaneously - orientation

Tags: android-layout, orientation, android

In my main Game Activity I force the orientation to portrait. This is clearly not a good idea on tablets. What is the best way to check the SDK version and not do this for tablets (or perhaps even force landscape)? I assume I then need to specify a layout-land-large folder and put the files in there. Is there anything else I need to do? I read something somewhere that I also need to specify screen sizes somewhere in the manifest.

```
    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

I.e. should it be in -large or xlarge?

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely [check out the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#support) here.

You can simply declare two different layouts in  and  folders specifying two different View orientations.

Please let me know if you need any clarification, and I'll get back to you :)

Hope this helped!

Comment: Hi Phoenix, I'd already looked at the documentation and it isn't that clear to me. A lot of it talks about how to define it in 3.2 but obviously I want one code base for phones and tablets. If I understand it correctly a 10" tablet is either 720 x 1280 mdpi or 800 x 1280mdpi. And it says that large is considered to be > 640 x 480 whilst xlarge is > 960 x 720. I assume then then I should be using large and not xlarge as the folder qualifier. Also how should my if statement read. I basically want to say if screenSize <= normal (640 wide) then set portrait else either do nothing or set landscape

Comment: Actually so far I've just created a values-large folder for my dimens.xml and that seems to be working very well. Still not sure how best to check for the screen size in the code though.

Answer (score 0):

`res/values` for handsets in portrait mode.

`res/values-sw600dp` for 7" tablet in portrait mode

`res/values-sw720dp` for 10" tablet in portrait mode

`res/values-sw720dp-land` for 10" tablet in landscape mode

and reference to Android Developer Guide -- [How to support multiple screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#support)